# Jenkins and npm/jest in jenkins pipelines: enoent events.js

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently configuring our jenkins jobs and encountered a problem when setting up a multipipeline project for one of our javascript projects.

This javascript project uses Jest for testing run with npm test:
    `"test": "jest --verbose"`

When jenkins executes the job though, it fails with a non-descriptive error. Just says failure. If I change the jenkinsfile to directly call 'jest' instead of 'npm test', it fails with an `ENOENT in event.js - line 160`, but does not provide more information as to what file would be missing or what can not be accessed.

If I run the tests manually on the machine running jenkins, it works, with the system install of nodejs, as well as with the nodejs jenkins plugin.

It also works in a regular project: If I just setup a regular project linked to our repo, it works, it runs the tests perfectly, so it is specifically linked to the pipeline setup. Maybe something to do with the sandbox groovy runs in?

My jenkinsfile is:

```
node('master') { // <1>
  echo "Running ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
  checkout scm

  stage('Test') {
        env.NODE_ENV = "test"

        def nodejs = tool name: 'Recent Node', type: 'jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation'

        env.PATH = "${nodejs}/bin:${env.PATH}"

        sh 'node -v'
        sh 'npm prune'
        sh 'npm install'

        //sh 'npm install -g jest'

        sh 'npm test --verbose'
  }

 ...
}
```

Some more information, the exact output from Jenkins:

```
[Westeros_Shae_master-LLONGEYFZHPPZGPNCY5NX2JCP6ERHRXGIYARHJWEF662AIZ4TGDQ] Running shell script
+ npm test --verbose npm info it worked if it ends with ok npm verb cli [ '/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin/node', npm verb cli   '/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin/npm', npm verb cli   'test', npm verb cli   '--verbose' ] npm info using npm@4.0.5 npm info using node@v7.4.0 npm verb run-script [ 'pretest', 'test', 'posttest' ] npm info lifecycle shae@1.0.0~pretest: shae@1.0.0 npm info lifecycle shae@1.0.0~test: shae@1.0.0 shae@1.0.0 test /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Westeros_Shae_master-LLONGEYFZHPPZGPNCY5NX2JCP6ERHRXGIYARHJWEF662AIZ4TGDQ jest --verbose

npm verb lifecycle shae@1.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true npm verb lifecycle shae@1.0.0~test: PATH: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Westeros_Shae_master-LLONGEYFZHPPZGPNCY5NX2JCP6ERHRXGIYARHJWEF662AIZ4TGDQ/node_modules/.bin:/Users/jenkins/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/nodejs/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH npm verb lifecycle shae@1.0.0~test: CWD: /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Westeros_Shae_master-LLONGEYFZHPPZGPNCY5NX2JCP6ERHRXGIYARHJWEF662AIZ4TGDQ npm info lifecycle shae@1.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
```

Comment: Are the node_modules in your Jenkins Pipeline Workspace? Can be found under "Pipeline Steps" - "Allocate node : Start ..."

Comment: I have to admit that I am not 100% sure where to find the Allocate node: Start, but as far as I can see node_modules is in my workspace.

Comment: are you sure you have everything setup properly for `jenkins` user?